# How to run a (changing) JavaScript file within a loop in R?

Tags: javascript, r, phantomjs

I am working in `R`, but I have a small `Phantom JS` script that opens and writes a webpage to a file (`scrape_webpages.js`). There are many webpages that I need to download, named in a standard format (i.e. `http://webpage.net/2018`), where the last part (the year) varies. The `Phantom JS` script takes two arguments that need to vary: the path where to save the webpage and the webpage address.

Now I know how to make a loop and iterate over the range of years I need to generate addresses and paths in `R`. And I can run an individual `js` script from within `R` with the `system` function.

But (how) can I include the `js` (with varying arguments) script in an `R` loop? Alternatively, the loop can be implemented within the `js` script itself, but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks for your help.

(N.B. I cannot do what the `js` script does directly in `R`)

Comment: Have you tried the R package `webshot`, which is an interface to the PhantomJS API?

Comment: had a look at `webshot` but does not seem to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved this. It's a bit of a hack, but might still be useful to somebody:

(1)  Create the `js` for the first year for which data is to be downloaded

(2)  Start a loop in which you:

(2a) read the `js` file for the previous year as a string with `readChar`

(2b) change what needs to be changed in this file-as-a-string with `gsub`

(2c) save the edited string as a new `.js` file with a new name with  `writeLines`

(3) Start a new loop executing each of these `js` files with `system` function (this last step can be integrated into the previous loop if desired).

And, presto!